# Volume of a flat top cylinder surrounded by half-Gaussian annular "sidewalls"

Tags: integration

We have a “flat top” cylinder surrounded by a “half Gaussian” annulus.
We know the total power under the surface
Given: R, ω0, and power under the surface
Find:  A closed form expression for I0, (Zmax)(i.e., height of the flat top)
Where:
R is the radius of the "flat top" cylinder
ω0 is the radius of the Gaussian (in excess of R), at Z=I0*1/e^2 intensity
V is the total power
[cylinder surrounded by half-Gaussian annulus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWqlG.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @John: Have you, by chance, recently learned how to integrate in polar coordinates? Either way, could you please explain where you're stuck?

Comment: Thank you. I have found the solution

Answer (score 0):

---

[Integration of a flat top cylinder with Gaussian annulus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCQGD.png)